# mongodb is not working with cli in codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter-3

I am trying to use code-igniter cli commands

while calling same thing from browser mongodb is working but calling from terminal showing error

**Controller file**

```php
     class Todo extends MX_Controller {

     function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
         echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
         $this-load-model('sms_mongo_model'); // using 

     }

     public function message($to = 'World')
     {
         echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
     }
 }

**Sms_mongo_model.php**

     class Sms_mongo_model extends CI_Model
     {

         function __construct()
         {
             parent::__construct();
             $this-load-library('mongo_db');
         }

         public function add_leads_job($in = []){
             $object = $in;
             $this-mongo_db-BulkWrite-update(
                 ['job_id' = $in['job_id']],
                 ['$set' = $object],
                 ['multi' = false, 'upsert' = true]
             );
             /* calling bulk driver */
             $this-mongo_db-executeBulkWrite('sms_marketing_jobs',$this-mongo_db-BulkWrite);
         }
 }
```

while calling from browser mongodb is working fine.

On terminal i am getting this error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type:        Error Message:
>   Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I was using cli and php cli was using different php.ini file.

So I append extension= mongodb.so to respective file and it start working.